Output List in JSX
I am trying to output a HTML list in JSX.
Here is how I build the array:
let seasonsList = [];

for (var i=0; i < jsonData.data.campaigns.list.length; i++) {
    seasonsList.push(<li key={i}>{jsonData.data.campaigns.list[i].name}</li>);
}

 

When I try to output this list I get nothing inside the ul tags
return (
    <ul>{seasonsList}</ul>
);

How can I output the list of names inside the ul tags?

What happens if you console.log the seasonsList?

@JakubKotrs I get 0
:
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: 'li', key: '0', ref: null, props: {…}, …}

also console log jsonData.data.campaigns.list to make sure it's not empty or undefined.

@JohnnyMissile its empty when I log it outside the fetch

@cpcdev where is your fetch at, and where do you save the result? is jsonDate a state?


make sure your jsonData.data.campaigns.list contains the expected data

instead using for loop you should try this appraoch
let seasonsList = jsonData?.data?.campaigns?.list?.map((campaign, index) => (
  <li key={index}>{campaign.name}</li>
));

return <ul>{seasonsList}</ul>


you can try with the below code and also make sure that the index which you are passing as a key prop to the  tag
const seasonsList = jsonData?.data?.campaigns>.list?.map((campaign, index) => (
  <li key={index}>{campaign.name}</li>
));

return (
  <ul>{seasonsList}</ul>
);


if still the problem exist then try with passing some unique values which is coming from the data you get in the key prop in  tag for example :
 <li key={campaign.id}>{campaign.name}</li>

